How to replicate the font and color in TOC of the documentation of class memoir?
I am writing my thesis in class memoir:
\documentclass{memoir}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Notations}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\section{Background}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some SDEs}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some PDEs}

\end{document}

From the documentation of class memoir, I have found that its TOC is very nice:

I have looked at the source code (here and here) of the documentation, but I could not find how to replicate the font and color of its TOC. Could you explain how to do so?

The colors are produced by hyperref. The color is defined by \definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

The color is courtesy of hyperref.
Browsing the code for the manual, you find
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

(Peter Wilson is British, you know).
Here's an example.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=linkcolour,
}

\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter title}

\section{Section title}

\end{document}


For the font, I suggest NewPX (the manual uses legacy clones of Palatino).
Adding \usepackage{newpx} you get

I don't find the mix of Palatino with Computer Modern Sans very appealing.

Thank you for your answer. Can we set the font NewPX for only TOC and the titles of chapters/sections/subsections/subsubsections?

@Akira Possible? Yes. Typographically sound? I don't think so.
